# How to check a specific check box in gridview from codebehind?c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvApplDocs" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="1050px"
                   DataKeyNames="doc_name_eng" Font-Names="Calibri" OnRowCommand="gvApplDocs_RowCommand"
                   OnRowDataBound="gvApplDocs_RowDataBound">
                   <Columns>
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sl No" ItemStyle-Width="40px">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:Label ID="lblRowNumber" Text='<%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>' runat="server" />
                           </ItemTemplate>
                       </asp:TemplateField>
                       <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Application Document">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:Label ID="lbl_doc_name_eng" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("doc_name_eng") %>'></asp:Label>
                           </ItemTemplate>
                       </asp:TemplateField>
                       <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HeaderText="Document Uploaded Y/N">
                           <ItemTemplate>
                               <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" Enabled="false" runat="server" />
                           </ItemTemplate>
                       </asp:TemplateField>
                   </Columns>
               </asp:GridView>
```

I want to check the checkbox depending upon the no. of documents i have for example
if I have four document with id(1,2,3,4)
I want to check the correspondig checkbox in grid. Help me out guys

is there any method to particularly check the checkbox in gridview from code behind
Thanks in Advance

Comment: In code behind, loop through all Rows in your GridView.  While in each row, do a FindControl("chkRow") and cast that to an object you can use to determine if it's checked or not.  Example:  ````Checkbox chk = row.FindControl("chkRow"); if (chk.Checked) { ... } ````

Comment: The check box has to be Checked  from code behind if the document is present, the datatable dt posses the documents, depending upon the doc_id respective checkbox has to be checked.

Comment: Do you have a GridView RowDataBound event in your code-behind? If so, you need to do something similar there.  It looks like you do "gvApplDocs_RowDataBound" -- can you post that code in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generic answer for you. I think you can take this and update your own RowDataBound event (or include your event in your question and I will use that in an updated answer for you)

Front-End

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvTest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="gvTest_RowDataBound">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code-behind RowDataBound event

```
void gvTest_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Row.RowType)
    {
        case DataControlRowType.DataRow:

            // assumes you passed in the DataTable.Rows as the DataSource
            DataRow row = (DataRow)e.Row.DataItem;
            if (row != null)
            {
                CheckBox chkRow = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkRow");
                if (chkRow != null)
                {
                    // logic check from our row....number of documents?
                    int numberOfDocs = (int)row["number_of_dcos"];
                    if (numberOfDocs > 0)
                    {
                        chkRow.Checked = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chkRow.Checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }

            break;

        case DataControlRowType.Header:
            break;

        case DataControlRowType.Footer:
            break;
    }
}
```